# Not able to set OnApplyRedirect in OWIN. Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

I need to define the Login page on an ASP.NET MVC 5.2 website using Owin so I tried:

```
public void Configure(IAppBuilder application) {

  UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);

  // Testing routes > All returned null 
  var home = url.Action("home", "index");

  var homeT4MVC = url.Action(MVC.Home.Index());

  var login = url.Action("user", "login");   

  var loginT4MVC = url.Action(MVC.User.Login());

  application.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider() {
      OnApplyRedirect = context => context.Response.Redirect(
        login.AddRouteValues(new { culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name }))
      )}
  });
}
```

What is strange is that all the routes I tested are null ... But I have 116 routes in url.RouteCollection and I am able to use all my T4MVC routes.

What might be wrong here?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

your routes will be generated later in a mvc application. here is owin's middleware, which is executed before the web application.